# How to initialize a generic inside another generic using the same type in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to use a generic struct inside another generic struct.

```swift
public protocol FloatConvertible {
    init(_ other:Float)
    init(_ other:Double)
    init(_ x:FloatConvertible)

    func _asOther<T:FloatConvertible>() -> T
}

extension FloatConvertible {
    public init(_ x:FloatConvertible) {self = x._asOther()}
}
extension Float : FloatConvertible {
    public func _asOther<T:FloatConvertible>() -> T {return T(self)}
}

extension Double : FloatConvertible {
    public func _asOther<T:FloatConvertible>() -> T {return T(self)}
}

struct B<U> {
    var multVar: U
    init(multVar: U) {
        self.multVar = multVar
    }
}

struct A<T> {
    var array = [B<T>]()
    init(_ a: [T]) {
        for f in a {
            array.append(B<T>(multVar: f))
        }
    }
    func printResult(){
      var result: Float = 1.0
      for x in array {
          result = result * Float(x.multVar)
      }
    }

}

var array = [3.0,2.0]
var structA = A<FloatConvertible>(array)
structA.printResult()
```

```
generics.swift:37:29: error: initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'T' conform to 'BinaryInteger'
          result = result * Float(x.multVar)
                            ^
Swift.Float:3:23: note: where 'Source' = 'T'
    @inlinable public init<Source>(_ value: Source) where Source : BinaryInteger
```

I am getting this error.

But when I used a single variable instead of an array, type casted it to a Float and printed it, it worked.

Is this the correct way to initialise a generic struct inside another generic struct using the same type? If not, what can I do?

The actual code I'm using is below:

```swift
// struct defining a data series
public struct Series<T,U> {
    public var barGraphSeriesOptions = BarGraphSeriesOptions()
    public var scatterPlotSeriesOptions = ScatterPlotSeriesOptions()
    public var pairs = [Pair<T,U>]()
    public var scaledPairs = [Pair<T,U>]()
    public var maxY: Float = 0
    public var minY: Float = 0
    public var label = "Plot"
    public var color : Color = .blue
    public var startColor: Color? = nil
    public var endColor: Color? = nil
    public init() {}

    public init(pairs : [Pair<T,U>], label l: String, startColor : Color = .lightBlue, endColor : Color = Color.lightBlue, hatchPattern: BarGraphSeriesOptions.Hatching = .none, scatterPattern: ScatterPlotSeriesOptions.ScatterPattern = .circle){
        self.pairs = pairs
        label = l
        self.startColor = startColor
        self.endColor = endColor
        barGraphSeriesOptions.hatchPattern = hatchPattern
        scatterPlotSeriesOptions.scatterPattern = scatterPattern
    }
    public init(pairs : [Pair<T,U>], label l: String, color c: Color = Color.lightBlue, hatchPattern: BarGraphSeriesOptions.Hatching = .none, scatterPattern: ScatterPlotSeriesOptions.ScatterPattern = .circle){
        self.pairs = pairs
        label = l
        color = c
        barGraphSeriesOptions.hatchPattern = hatchPattern
        scatterPlotSeriesOptions.scatterPattern = scatterPattern
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you simply use a generic FloatingPoint type?

Comment: @Leo Dabus Although it isn't written here I would also like the protocol to allow conversion between Int. My main concern is about initialising the array of struct B using the same generic type used for A. Like I also want to be able to write 
var structA = A<CustomStringConvertible>(). But just for the example I've used FloatConvertible.

Comment: show a practical exemple. If you want it to be generic why would you convert them to a specific type? `struct A<T: BinaryFloatingPoint> {`
    let array: [T]
}`

Comment: `let  arrayy: [CGFloat] = [3.0,2.0]
var structA = A(array: arrayy)
structA.printResult()`

Comment: `extension A {
    func printResult() {
        var result: T = 1.0
        for x in array {
            result *= result * x
            print(result)
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @Leo Dabus I've added my actual code in the question. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I want to initialise the Pair with the same generic as Series. Like, to plot a Scatter Plot we'd require Pair<FloatConvertible,FloatConvertible> and for Bar graph, Pair<CustomStringConvertible,FloatConvertible>

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the fact that, in the implementation of `A<T>`, your generic parameter as no constraint, which means it could be *anything* (from a `Float`, to a custom struct/class).

This imply that you *can't* convert it into a `Float`. For example, if I create an instance of `A` with a custom struct, the float conversion is impossible.

```swift
struct A<T> {
    var array = [B<T>]()

    init(_ a: [T]) {
        for f in a {
            array.append(B<T>(multVar: f))
        }
    }
}

struct User {}
A([User(), User()]) // this is a valid initialization
```

But at this point, you cant just cast a `User` into a `Float`

```swift
Float(User()) // error
```

You can solve this either by:

- adding a constraint to the generic parameter (in the `A` struct)
- restraining the `printResult()` method implementation when `T` conforms to `FloatConvertible`

#### Constraint `A<T>`

```swift
struct A<T: FloatConvertible> {
    var array = [B<T>]()

    init(_ a: [T]) {
        for f in a {
            array.append(B<T>(multVar: f))
        }
    }

    func printResult() {
        var result: Float = 1.0
        for x in array {
            result = result * Float(x.multVar)
        }
    }
}

var array = [3.0, 2.0]
var structA = A(array)
structA.printResult()
```

#### Constraint `printResult()`

```swift
struct A<T: FloatConvertible> {
    var array = [B<T>]()

    init(_ a: [T]) {
        for f in a {
            array.append(B<T>(multVar: f))
        }
    }
}

extension A where T: FloatConvertible {
    func printResult() {
        var result: Float = 1.0
        for x in array {
            result = result * Float(x.multVar)
        }
    }
}

var array = [3.0, 2.0]
var structA = A(array)
structA.printResult()
```